# Display FPS on screen? Java

Tags: java, frame-rate

I am new to developing games. I have this code:

```
private void render() //renders graphics
{
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null)
    {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0,WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    g.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 18)); //doesnt work
    g.drawString(Color.BLUE + "FPS: " + Color.ORANGE + frames, 50, 50);

    handler.render(g);
    hud.render(g);

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

And I have a question... The g.drawString that is supposed to display fps doesn't display the fps... What am I dong wrong? This is in java btw...

Comment: First of all: if you want to draw a string in two different colors, you'll have to first set the color and then draw the string, like `g.setColor(someColor); g.drawString(someString , 10 , 10);`. Two operations, not a single one. Your code will merge the colors and the rest of the string into a single string.

Comment: ok thanks... let me try it... TY IT WORKS!!